# calling a PHP method where name is a variable

Tags: php, variables, methods

I am trying to call several methods from a class 'Content', i.e.

```
$content .= Content::page_contact_us();
```

Except page_contact_us can be anything...

I tried

```
$method = 'Content::page_contact_us()';

$content .= $$method_name;
```

And `$content` was blank...

Comment: how about `call_user_func($method_name)` ? But remove the `()` from the variable declaration.

Comment: The help pages have some [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).

Comment: `Content::$method_name()`

Answer (score 2):

A method name can be a variable, in the same way a [function name can be a variable](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php):

```
<?php

class Content 
{
    public static function foo()
    {   
        echo 'Hello';
    }   
}

$name = 'foo';
echo Content::$name(); // Outputs 'Hello'
```

If you really do need/mean *anything*, [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) allows calling anything:

```
$result = call_user_func('time'); // a function

$result = call_user_func('Content::foo'); // a static method
$result = call_user_func(['Content', 'foo']); // a static method

$result = call_user_func([$contentObject 'someMethod']); // an instance method
```

There are further examples in [the callable docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: $content .= Content::$method_name(); worked nicely...thank you...

But just for completion -

$content .= call_user_func(['Content', $method_name]);
this caused the following problem:
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context....
in the database utility function...

Comment: `in the database utility function` this is not related to your question.

Comment: without going into detail... it is exactly the same method... just used in 2 different ways... both ways are supposed to be static but seem non equivalent in another way... what is the difference?

Comment: [there is no difference](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/39f3a5b8223487a6546655684861d9aa) - whatever you are looking at is not related to the question, you have (directly or indirectly) called `$this->something` when not in an object. Please investigate and ask another question if you need to, it is not related to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax to call variable functions:

```
$func = 'foo';
$func();        // This calls foo()
```

[PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

**Or, in your case:**

```
$method = 'Content::page_contact_us';
$content .= $method();
```

Comment: `Or, in your case:` [is a fatal error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OQAQ6.png) in php < 7.0.

Comment: Check out AD7six's answer for a far better way to do this. Variable function and class calls are better handled with [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Comment: @Machavity No, they are not. Stay with `$method()` but use `$method = ['Content', 'page_contact_us']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using PHP's `call_user_func()`. Here's how:

```
<?php
    class Content{
        public static function whatever(){
            return "This is a response from whatever Method inside the Content Class...";
        }
    }


    $method     = 'whatever';
    $content    = "";
    $content   .= Content::whatever();

    $content2   = call_user_func(array('Content', $method));

    var_dump($content);
    var_dump($content2);

     //RESPECTIVELY DISPLAYS::              
     'This is a response from whatever Method inside the Content Class...' (length=67)
     'This is a response from whatever Method inside the Content Class...' (length=67)
```